# C++ function declaration syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

What is the meaning of the following excerpt:

```
  : program_(program), max_iters_(max_iterations), num_iters_(0)
```

in this piece of code:

```
Search::Search(const string& program, int max_iterations)
  : program_(program), max_iters_(max_iterations), num_iters_(0) 
{
  max_branch_ = 0; 
 // ...
}
```

Comment: See my answer to [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1272707/96780)

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903248/initializing-fields-in-constructor-initializer-list-vs-constructor-body

Comment: Just curious, but where are people learning C++ today.  I can't imagine any introductory text which didn't explain this.

Comment: @JamesKanze my first contact with c++ was at the university, and the script did not cover this. i ran into it when i first had a class without a default constructor.

Comment: @JamesKanze Exactly, exactly. I'm wondering too. When people ask questions like "why `"foo"[0] = 'a';` segfaults", then I always ask back "what did your beginner C textbook says about it?"...

Comment: i found my answer in  [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/what-does-a-colon-following-a-c-constructor-name-do) ? tnx @DanielDaranas.

Comment: @H2CO3 That one's almost excusable.  It was guaranteed to work in pre-ISO C (and described as guaranteed to work in K&R-I).

Answer (score 4):

What you are referring to is called initializer list. A class or struct can initialize member variables using this list in its constructors.

Example:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() : member_(0) {}

    private:
        int member_;
};
```

The initialization list is especially important if you have members that have no default constructor - because when you reach in the body of the constructor, every member will have been created. If you did not choose a proper constructor for this member, compilation will fail.

Example:

```
struct bar { bar(int) {} };

struct foo
{
    foo() 
        : bar_(0) // does not compile without this line
                  // because the compiler will try to default
                  // construct otherwise
    {}

    private:
        bar bar_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a constructor initialization list. Presumable, `Search` is a class with data members `program_`, `max_iters` and `num_iters`.

Comment: tnx for response. what is different between initializing "max_branch_" in body of function and "max_iters_" before body?

Comment: @NewMrd you cannot *initialize* a data member in the body of the constructor, you can only *assign* a value to it. By the time you get to the body of the constructor, all data members have been initialized.

Comment: look at [link]https://github.com/mabdi/CREST/blob/master/src/run_crest/concolic_search.cc line 57.

Comment: @NewMrd what about it?

Comment: my quesion is why not all data members has been initialized in initialization list?

Comment: @NewMrd No idea, ask the person who write the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not a function declaration but a class constructor implementation

The class Search declared before a ctor with 2 parameters and now your are in front of its implementation where the parameters are use to initialize data member.

Comment: I am nitpicking, but a constructor is a function. It's mentioned in the C++11 standard within 12.1 as a special function, but a function nonetheless.

Comment: why "num_iters_" is initilized in initialization list but "max_branch_" is initilized in body?