# No initializer list vs. initializer list with empty pairs of parentheses

Tags: c++, initializer-list

This is copy paste from this topic [Initializing fields in constructor - initializer list vs constructor body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903248/initializing-fields-in-constructor-initializer-list-vs-constructor-body)

The author explains the following equivalence:

```
    public : Thing(int _foo, int _bar){
        member1 = _foo;
        member2 = _bar;
    }

is equivalent to

    public : Thing(int _foo, int _bar) : member1(), member2(){
        member1 = _foo;
        member2 = _bar;
    }
```

My understanding was that

- snippet 1 is a case of default-initialization (because of the absence of an initializer list)
- snippet 2 is a case of value-initialization (empty pairs of parentheses).

How are these two equivalent?

Comment: The two are only equivalent for non-POD user defined types. For built-ins, default initialization means no initialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not all user-defined types, *only* non-pod types!

Comment: @Nawaz Good point. Fixed.

Comment: @Nawaz [class.base.init]/8 says the members are default-initialized if there's no initializer in the *mem-initializer-list* (and no *brace-or-equal-initializer*), and [dcl.init]/7 says that default-initialization for *any* class type means calling the default ctor. Therefore, for a POD class, the default ctor will be called.

Comment: @DyP: A POD class can't contain a user-defined ctor, nor can anything it aggregates. Therefore, the default ctors for it and whatever it contains must be the sorts of ones that are basically NOPs (e.g., like `int`'s).

Comment: @DyP: The implicitly defined default constructor for POD doesn't initialize the members. 12.1/6 says *"The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class **with no ctor-initializer** (12.6.2) and an empty compound-statement."*

Comment: Btw: You should remove the assignment in the second constructor.

Comment: @Nawaz It's not POD-ness which makes a difference; it's rather whether the class has a user defined constructor or not.  (If a class has virtual functions, for example, it is not a POD, but the behavior in the two cases is still different.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, that is true.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Under the *as-if-rule* they can be equivalent for built-ins as well. (Please, see my answer and point out any mistake that I might have made.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct (assuming `member1` and `member2`
have type `int).  The two forms are *not* equivalent; in the
first, the members are not initialized at all, and cannot be
used until they have been assigned.  In the second case, the
members will be initialized to 0.  The two formulations are only
equivalent if the members are class types with user defined
constructors.

Comment: "The two formulations are only equivalent if the members are class types with user defined constructors." And if the implicitly declared default ctor is deleted (making both versions ill-formed).

Comment: @DyP Or if it isn't accessible.  Any time one of the two forms doesn't compile, the code is clearly not equivalent.

Comment: "Any time one of the two forms doesn't compile" Huh? What I meant was that *value-initialization* is defined as *default-initialization* in two cases: 1) If there's a user-provided default ctor 2) If the default ctor is deleted.

Comment: @DyP: Under the as-if-rule they can be equivalent for non class types as well. (Please, see my answer and point out any mistake that I might have made.)

Comment: @CassioNeri Could be.  If you accidentally use them before initialization, you have undefined behavior, so the compiler can do anything it wants, including making the code work by moving the initialization up where it belongs.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "if you accidentally use them before initialization, you have undefined behavior". Not necessarilly. If they are of type `int`, for instance, their initial value is indeterminate (8.5/11) but the semantics of the program is well defined. So, even without undefined behavior, thanks to the as-if-rule, the two snippets might (but not necessarily will) be equivalent. The discussion also depends on the definition of "equivalent". I'm considering "generate the same code" as a definition of equivalent.

Comment: @CassioNeri If you use the value of an `int` before it has been initialized, you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are right but the author is *kind of* right too!

Your interpretation is completely correct as are the answers given by others. In summary the two snippets are equivalent if `member1` and `member2` are non-POD types.

For certain POD types they are also equivalent in *some sense*. Well, let's simplify a little more and assume `member1` and `member2` have type `int`. Then, under the *as-if-rule* the complier is *allowed* to replace the second snippet with the first one. Indeed, in the second snippet the fact that `member1` is first initlialized to `0` is not observable. Only its assignment to `_foo` is. This is the same reasoning that allows the compiler to replace these two lines

```
int x = 0;
x = 1;
```

with this one

```
int x = 1;
```

For instance, I've compiled this code

```
struct Thing {

    int member1, member2;

    __attribute__ ((noinline)) Thing(int _foo, int _bar)
        : member1(), member2() // initialization line
    {
        member1 = _foo;
        member2 = _bar;
    }
};

Thing dummy(255, 256);
```

with GCC 4.8.1 using option `-O1`. (The `__atribute((noinline))__` prevents the compiler from inlining the function). Then the generated assembly code is the same regardless whether the initialization line is present or not:

**`-O1` with or without initialization**

```
   0:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
   4:   89 01                   mov    %eax,(%ecx)
   6:   8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
   a:   89 41 04                mov    %eax,0x4(%ecx)
   d:   c2 08 00                ret    $0x8
```

On the other hand, when compiled with `-O0` the assembly code is different depending on whether the initialization line is present or not:

**`-O0` without initialization**

```
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
   6:   89 4d fc                mov    %ecx,-0x4(%ebp)
   9:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   c:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   f:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
  11:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
  14:   8b 55 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
  17:   89 50 04                mov    %edx,0x4(%eax)
  1a:   c9                      leave  
  1b:   c2 08 00                ret    $0x8
  1e:   90                      nop
  1f:   90                      nop
```

**`-O0` with initialization**

```
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
   6:   89 4d fc                mov    %ecx,-0x4(%ebp)
   9:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax   ; extra line #1
   c:   c7 00 00 00 00 00       movl   $0x0,(%eax)       ; extra line #2
  12:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax   ; extra line #3
  15:   c7 40 04 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%eax)    ; extra line #4
  1c:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
  1f:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
  22:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
  24:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
  27:   8b 55 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
  2a:   89 50 04                mov    %edx,0x4(%eax)
  2d:   c9                      leave  
  2e:   c2 08 00                ret    $0x8
  31:   90                      nop
  32:   90                      nop
  33:   90                      nop
```

Notice that `-O0` with initialization has four extra lines (marked above) than `-O0` without initialization. These extra lines initialize the two members to zero.

Comment: Even for non-POD class types they may yield the same code. However, they're semantically equivalent only if the member types don't have a user-provided default ctor, or if the default ctor is deleted. (That includes certain non-POD classes as well, see James Kanze's [comment to the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407228/no-initializer-list-vs-initializer-list-with-empty-pairs-of-parentheses/19407534?noredirect=1#comment28767482_19407228).)