# Not able to call base class constructor from dericed class with parameter in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, visibility, derived-class

I have below scenario in c++ within DEV c++

```
class base{
    int i=0;
    public:
         base(){
            cout<<"base default constructor"<<endl;
         }
         base(int i){
             cout<<"base with int"<<endl;
         }
};

class derive : public base{
    int j;
    public:
        derive(){
            cout<<"derive default";
        }
        derive(int i){
            int k=5;
            base(k);//////error 
            cout<<"derived with int "<<i<<endl;
        }
        void fun(int i){
            cout<<"finction "<<i<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    derive d(9);

}
```

After running following error is coming
[Error] conflicting declaration 'base k'
[Error] 'k' has a previous declaration as 'int k'
Why this error is coming.
Its working fine when i call base(5) with any parameter except declared in derived constructor.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "DEV c++" is not a compiler.

Comment: Hi, yes its temporary and i am not initializing constructor. But i want to know why base(5) or base(j) works inside derived() but not base(i).

Answer (score 1):

If you call the base constructor within the derived class on the implicit parameter, it needs to be done in the [field initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903248/initializing-fields-in-constructor-initializer-list-vs-constructor-body) like so:

```
    derive(int i) : base(i) {
        cout<<"derived with int "<< i <<endl;
    }
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/diFXFD)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base{
public:
    base(){
        cout<<"base default constructor"<<endl;
    }
    base(int i){
        cout<<"base with int "<<i<<endl;
    }
};

class derive : public base{

public:
    int j;
    int k;
    derive(){
        cout<<"derive default\n";
    }
    derive(int i){
        k=5;
        base(this->k);//////error
        cout<<"derived with int "<<i<<endl;
    }
    void fun(int i){
        cout<<"finction "<<i<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    derive p(10);


}
```

Comment: please explain this answer a bit. code only answers are mostly not of much value. thank u! keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

There are two interpretations of what `base(k)` could be:

1. it could be a the creation of temporary
2. it could be a variable declaration: the variable name can be in parenthesis

Out of these two choices, the compiler uses the second one: if something can be either a declaration or an expression, the declaration is chosen. This is related to the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) although it isn't that. The effect is that in your use `base(k);` tries to define a variable named `k` of type `base`.

You can disambiguate the meaning using one of

1. `(base(k));`
2. `base{k};`

If `base` also had a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list<int>` these two can have different meanings.

Answer (score -1):

In `main()`

```
    base b(3);
    derive d(9);
    base b1(2);
```

//create explicit object and pass integer parameter.then try
also pass particular integer value in derive->base.
in derive

```
base(8);
```

And always print the value of variable acting weirdly in a program