# Trying to construct an object with another object as parameter

Tags: c++, class, object

https://imgur.com/gallery/pEw8fBs
https://pastebin.com/xvWFHrTU

My errors are posted above..I don't understand what's wrong with this code..I'm trying to construct a book with a date object inside of it.  Please help, this is my frist post as well!! :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }

class Date {
    int y, m, d;

public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y);
};

class Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string isbn;
    Date date;

public:
    Book(string t, string a, string id, Date d);
};

int main() {
    Book Charlie("charlie", "gates", "333H", Date(1, 2, 3));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I have ever seen a link to imgur as compiler errors on this site.

Comment: Please include the errors as text, inside the question (not through a link) TIA

Comment: You have not implemented either constructor (declared but not defined).

Comment: In C++ take arguments as `const` whenever possible, especially as a reference. `string t` makes a copy. `const string& t` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your constructors are declared but not defined

```
class Date {
    int y, m, d;

public:
    Date(int _d, int _m, int _y) : y(_y), m(_m), d(_d) {} // definition
};

class Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string isbn;
    Date date;

public:
    Book(string t, string a, string id, Date d)
    : title(t), author(a), isbn(id), data(d) {} // definition
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved if you declare a default constructor for `Date`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Date {
    int y, m, d;

public:
    // Default constructor which will be used in 'Book'
    Date() {}
    // Don't semicolon here, just two braces required
    Date(int d, int m, int y) {}
};

class Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string isbn;
    // Default constructor called here
    Date date;

public:
    // You can code everything inside the braces now
    // NOTE 2: Default constructor called here
    Book(string t, string a, string id, Date d) {}
};

int main() {
    Book Charlie("charlie", "gates", "333H", Date(1, 2, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except the non-default constructor disregards the inputs, surely those are meant to initialize the class members. And the OP should [prefer initialization lists instead of the constructor body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903248/initializing-fields-in-constructor-initializer-list-vs-constructor-body).

Comment: what if I didn't want to use the default constructor?  how would I go about validating each variable in the date through the book?

Comment: @Cluelesshint Simple. Use the initializer list to construct all the member variables.

Comment: @RohanBari I tried this..when I try and create the object above the date isn't stored correctly with the default constructor..i'm so lost on how to get it to not use default construct