# Assign child properties without effecting parent?

Tags: c++

Assuming I have two classes a parent and a child class each with its own property(s)

```
class Parent
{
private:
    int m_nParentX;
public:
    Parent(int nX)
    {
        m_nParentX = nX;
    }
    int GetParentX()
    {
        return m_nParentX;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
private:
    int m_nChildY;
public:
    Child(int nX, int nY) : Parent(nX)
    {
        m_nChildY = nY;
    }
    int GetChildY()
    {
        return m_nChildY;
    }
    
};
```

Then I have two instances of the Child class both with distinct values for each instance.

```
    Child a(10,20);
    Child b(30,40);
```

What I'd like to do is assign the properties of Child b to that of Child A; however I'd like to do this without effecting it's parent properties

If I do this

```
void Overwrite(Child* a, Child* b)
{
    *b = *a;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Child a(10,20);
    Child b(30,40);
    
    std::cout << a.GetParentX()<< ":" << a.GetChildY() << "\t" << b.GetParentX() << ":" << b.GetChildY() << std::endl;
    
    Overwrite(&a,&b);
    
    std::cout << a.GetParentX() << ":" << a.GetChildY() << "\t" << b.GetParentX() << ":" << b.GetChildY() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
10:20   30:40
10:20   10:20
```

Which is not exactly what I want since I don't want the parent's X of Child b which is 30 to be replaced with Child a parent value of 10.
Essentially I'd like to output to be

```
10:20   30:40
10:20   30:20
```

Is it possible to do a quick assignment of classes without effecting parent properties?

Comment: You need to write a function that does what you want, i.e. copies some attributes and not others between class instances.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thank you but I was hoping for a simpler way where I can avoid individual property assignments..

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `m_nParentX = nX` in the ctor body, use member initializer list.

Comment: @Kayla See [Initializing fields in constructor - initializer list vs constructor body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903248/initializing-fields-in-constructor-initializer-list-vs-constructor-body)

Comment: Thank you @user12002570 I'll do that in my code

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that the only thing that needs to be done, here, is to replace parameters `Child* a, Child* b` with `Parent* a, Parent* b`. Everything else can be left unchanged.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That does the opposite of what I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of the parent object first, `Parent pCopyOfB = *b;` then after you perform the assignment of the dereferenced pointers, cast b to its parent pointer and do a second assignment using the copy you saved earlier.

```
void Overwrite(Child* a, Child* b)
{
    Parent pCopyOfB = *b;
    *b = *a;
    Parent* pOfB = b;
    *pOfB = pCopyOfB;
}
```

This will restore the parent properties after overwriting the children properties. The output should be what you desired `10:20 30:20`

Comment: Yes! Why didn't I think of that! I get the restored parent attributes thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it complicated.

```
void Overwrite(Child* a, Child* b) {
    a->m_nChildY = b->GetChildY;
}
```

But better to take the arguments by reference:

```
void Overwrite(Child &a, const Child &b) {
    a.m_nChildY = b.GetChildY();
}
```

Or, even better, make it a member function:

```
void Child::Overwrite(const Child& b) {
    m_nChildY = b.GetChildY();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this only works if I have to assign every property manually.. In my case I might have 20 or 50 properties which I don't want to go through one by one and assign individually

Comment: @Kayla -- how are you going to assign 20 or 50 properties in the first place? You could use the compiler-generated assignment operator, until it doesn't do what you need. Then you're stuck again. But having 20 or 50 properties sounds like a design problem to begin with. No amount of coding can fix that.

Comment: It's not my code though, it's inheriting from a library which already assigns a bunch of properties for me that I do not want to change or keep track of